# Install with no existing OS?

Tags: system-installation

I have a PC with a brand new hard drive with no existing operating system. Is it possible to install Ubuntu without installing another OS first?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to obtain an installation medium such as a USB stick or livecd. Once you have one of those, you can use it to boot the computer. You don't need an installed OS on the pc to be able to boot.

Comment: I've downloaded the iso file onto a USB stick, and verified that my boot file allows booting from a removable device, but I get a "no operating system" error message

Comment: You need to do a bit more than just put the iso file on an USB stick. Check the relevant documentation on the Ubuntu site (I can't link easily, I'm typing this on a phone).

Comment: Also make sure you select the correct boot device from your uefi /bios

Comment: The .iso needs to be extracted and the partition needs to be marked as bootable. You can't just copy the .iso to the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, but you will need a CD/DVD or an USB with Ubuntu. Then you start the computer by Cd/USB, then you start the installation. This is possible because Ubuntu can start by Live CDs. Hope that it solved your problem =)

Answer (score 0):

If your BIOS is 100% you should be able to boot from a bootable USB drive with no problem. When you create the bootable USB drive the OS runs from the USB. Create a bootable usb drive using Universal USB Installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/  .Then change your BIOS boot order to boot from USB first.
After booting into the OS install Ubuntu from the install icon in the Desktop.

Comment: Also if you have a UEFI BIOS getthe 64bit version of Ubuntu as 32bit is not compatible with the UEFI BIOS.